# What is the difference between TF card memory and microSD card memory?

Tags: memory

Some android and windows tablet spec list 'TF card memory supported'. Is there a difference between 'TF card memory' and 'microSD card memory'?

Answer (score 13):

The microSD removable miniaturized Secure Digital flash memory cards were originally named T-Flash or TF, abbreviations of TransFlash. TransFlash and microSD cards are functionally identical allowing either to operate in devices made for the other.

[Secure Digital @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Micro)